# Reading and Writing from a binary file in C

Tags: c

This question has been asked many times before, but I've been trying this for hours with a variety of methods and I have no clue why this is wrong.

I've been writing C structs to a binary file using `fwrite()` and I've been trying to read from them using `fread()`. However, after I read from the file, all I get is nonsense answers in my struct when I try to print out the results. I've done a dump of the binary file and it looks fine, so I'm not quite sure what's wrong. Can anyone help? I'm running all of this on Ubuntu 16.04 32bit.

Struct:

```
typedef struct
{
    char file_name[256];
    int data_length;
} FileInfo;
```

Reading from file:

```
void displayInformation(FILE *file) {
  FileInfo fileInfo;

  if (fread(&fileInfo, sizeof(FileInfo), 1, file) < 0)
    printf("something went wrong with reading the file\n");

  printf("FileInfo: %s\n", fileInfo.file_name);
  printf("FileInfo: %d\n", fileInfo.data_length);
}
```

Writing to file:

```
void writeToFile() {
  ....
  uint8_t outbuf[MAX_BUF_SIZE];
  uint8_t *buf_ptr = outbuf;

  strncpy(((FileHeader *)outbuf)->file_name, fileName, sizeof(((FileHeader *)outbuf)->file_name) - 1);
  buf_ptr += sizeof(FileHeader);
   ....
  fwrite(outbuf, sizeof(FileInfo) + ((FileInfo *)outbuf)->data_length, 1, outputFile);
}
```

A hexdump of the file:

```
hexdump ./bin/example.bin

0000000 2f2e 6962 2f6e 7865 6d61 6c70 0065 0000
0000010 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
*
0000100 0034 0000 0001 0000 003e 0000 0000 0000
0000110 f362 4e1d 86c3 0e91 49c2 8e6c 6df6 d1bb
0000120 0002 0000 c437 3eeb 0003 0000 0792 0000
0000130 0004 0000 0000 0000
0000138
```

Thanks!

EDIT: I figured it out, it was because I wasn't reading the file from the right directory. Thanks everyone for their help though! It was really informative.

Comment: What is `FileInfo`? Does it contain pointers? You should edit your question to include a bit of info on that thing as it appears to be the source of your problem.

Comment: My apologies, I've updated the question and also included the binary file in question

Comment: No trouble. Smashing that thing into the file as-is looks pretty wasteful, that has a large, presumably mostly empty string buffer in it. When writing binary data like this consider using the `int` length field as a hint when reading the file back in as to how many bytes to read.

Comment: Maybe something has alignment/padding issues

Comment: Hmm.. noted thank you. Would that be causing my problems right now?

Comment: @Annabelle that's what I've been thinking, but is that something that I have to take care of manually or something else is messing it up?

Comment: Is the read and write from the same EXE?  If not, they could have different data alignment settings

Comment: Yes - the reading and writing here are both to the same binary file

Comment: Are you exceeding  MAX_BUF_SIZE?

Comment: Nope, I checked it just now - MAX_BUF_SIZE is 0x1000 and I'm only writing 312 bytes

Comment: You need to add the null char to outbuf filename after strncpy. 312 is too large, something is going wrong with the char array I suspect

Comment: `if (fread(&fileInfo, sizeof(FileInfo), 1, file) < 0)` can **never** be true.  Recommend `... <= 0`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd approach the problem as a first pass:

```
typedef struct
{
  // data_length should come first because it's not an arbitrary length and needs
  // to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary. This avoids ugly padding issues.
  int data_length;
  char file_name[256];
} FileInfo;

size_t writeFileInfo(FILE* f, FileInfo* fi) {
  return fwrite((void*)&fi->data_length, sizeof(int), 1, f) &&
    fwrite((void*)&fi->file_name, 1, fi->data_length, f);
}

size_t readFileInfo(FILE* f, FileInfo* fi) {
  size_t rv = 0;

  rv += fread((void*)&fi->data_length, sizeof(int), 1, f);
  rv += fread((void*)&fi->file_name, 1, fi->data_length, f);

  // Don't forget to NULL-terminate this string
  fi->file_name[fi->data_length] = 0;

  return rv;
}
```

These two functions break out the reading and writing operations into self-contained chunks of code, but they could just as easily be incorporated as part of another read/write function respectively.

The trick here is to write out a *variable length field* in your header as a length + string pair. Older file formats will use 8-bit or 16-bit values for these fields to avoid file bloat, but two extra bytes is probably not the end of the world here. You can trim those off by switching your length field to `uint16_t` if you feel that's necessary.

Here's a quick demonstration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void testWrite(char* path) {
  FILE* f = fopen(path, "w");

  FileInfo example;

  strcpy(example.file_name, "example.txt");
  example.data_length = strlen(example.file_name);

  writeFileInfo(f, &example);

  fclose(f);
}

void testRead(char* path) {
  FILE* f = fopen(path, "r");

  FileInfo example;

  readFileInfo(f, &example);

  printf("Read: %d / %s\n", example.data_length, example.file_name);

  fclose(f);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  char* testDump = "dump.bin";

  testWrite(testDump);
  testRead(testDump);

  return 0;
}
```

You should get a simple binary file with the right content in it. Pay very close attention to correctly NULL terminating your strings when reading in to raw buffers. C is always one tiny mistake away from a massive buffer overflow bug.

You'll want to get rid of that fixed-length character buffer and use something like `malloc()` to read in whatever size the size field dictates. Be careful with possibly huge values though. A single bit flip corruption error could trick your program into allocating 2GB of memory for no reason.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind why you chose to split up the reading by fields rather than the entire struct all at once?

Comment: It's because the struct technically contains a variable length field, so you should attack it as a multi-part problem: One for the fixed length fields, plus one for each variable length field. This is how a lot of binary files and binary protocols are organized internally. If you just smash your structure into the file you'll get a bunch of empty bytes at best, or at worst, random bits of memory that **could contain sensitive information**, so you don't want to do that.

Comment: Got it, thank you! I'll take your approach and give it another go

Comment: When programmers get sloppy and don't bother to properly zero out memory or trim off things that shouldn't be in there bad things can happen. Word was once hit by a bug where it'd include random chunks of memory from your computer, things completely unrelated to the file, or even from earlier edits, in places where the save routine was writing dirty buffer data.

Comment: This is all part of effective "serialization" techniques. I've mostly done this for network protocol applications where extra bytes needlessly increase transmission times, but the same general principles of using a simple, minimal representation can apply equally to binary files.

Comment: Sure beats writing a full `260` bytes per struct (plus any padding) to the file.

Answer (score 0):

It was a really simple error - it was because I wasn't reading the file at all. Changing the if statement to be `<=0` helped me track that down.

From:

```
if (fread(&fileInfo, sizeof(FileInfo), 1, file) < 0)
    printf("something went wrong with reading the file\n");
```

To:

```
if (fread(&fileInfo, sizeof(FileInfo), 1, file) <= 0)
    printf("something went wrong with reading the file\n");
```